# how to get historical data from wolfram alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

The following command give historical data from 21th April 2017 to 19th April 2018. Which is about 1 year. How do i get this result for past three years from wolfram alpha.

```
TimeSeries[First@WolframAlpha["USD to EUR",{{"History",1},"ComputableData"}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there could be some improvements to support for some date specifications here, but:

```
TimeSeries@First@WolframAlpha["USD to EUR from 2015 to 2018", 
{{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

?